# ViewState is Empty OnPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

My problem is that I save a `DataTable` on a `ViewState`, but when the page postbacks (gridview row editing click) it returns `null`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("c:\\teste.xml");
        gv_xml.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
        gv_xml.DataBind();
        ViewState.Add("dt", ds.Tables[1]);
        SaveViewState();
    }
}

protected void gv_xml_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gv_xml.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    gv_xml.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
    gv_xml.DataBind();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the method ViewState.Add for

```
ViewState[dt]=ds.Tables[1];
```

That should work, if it doesn't you need to check if your web.config has the viewstate enabled

```
     <system.web>
<pages enableViewState="false" />
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I have changed to ViewState[dt]=ds.Tables[1]; and it still doesn't work. I have checked the web.config too and ViewState is Enabled

Comment: is your method ReadXML returning something different than null? maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Yes my ReadXml method is returning a list of items, but when the page postbacks the value on the viewstate and on the gridview is lost

Comment: remove the line SaveViewState(); you dont need to save viewstate since is like a 'Session' value once you assing it, its saved within the context.